# SlidingMenu for non ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, slidingmenu

I'm trying to use Jeremy Feinstein's SlidingMenu in my application. Issue is I'm not using ActionBarSherlock and don't want to use it. I'm using Android's default ActionBar and quite happy with it. Now where to find the SlidingMenu implementation which is not dependent on ABS? I also don't have time to completely implement it on my own like the one used in Prixing app. Any Help, anybody?

EDIT:
I'm already using NavigationDrawer but want to animate ActionBar+MainContent with drawer animation like SlidingMenu does.

Comment: Do you mean the `Navigation Drawer`? http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Comment: I think for higher versions you do not need to use ABS for sliding menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to implement Action Bar Sherlock For J. Feinstein's Sliding menu. Grab the code which is being used with ABS, the same code (you can remove ABS code from it if you're not using ABS) will work for native action bar.